# How to use translation strings in flutter, and use Multiple languages

Tags: flutter

Kindly guide How to use multiple languages in Flutter, how to give the option to the user to switch between languages.

I have some strings to use in Flutter for multiple languages

English

```
"sensor_title": "SENSORS",
"sensor_gyroscope_title": "GYROSCOPE",
"sensor_accelerometer_title": "Accelerometer",
```

Turkish

```
"sensor_title": "SENSÖRLER",
"sensor_gyroscope_title": "JİROSKOP",
"sensor_accelerometer_title": "İvmeölçer",
```

Comment: Using the code below each time you want to translate a String just invoke Translator class like this `Translator.of(context).translate("sensor_title");` for instance

Comment: This assumes that you have json files saved in a `i18n` folder at the root of your project

Comment: You can also use getx dependency, it is so simple not only for localisation but State management, route management also..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple options you can try:

- Implement [i18n](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) for your app:
  With this, you need to implement the config yourself to make your app internationalized. You can use the build_runner to generate most of the config for you. What is left is just putting your key/value pairs of words into the json files.
- Use the [easy_localization package](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization): This package is what I usually use for small scale app since it does the heavy work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package it's easy to customize your translations and make offline multi language app. Just check on the internationalization part.